Why O(NlogN) algorithm performs better than O(N) algorithm on leetcode?
I was solving a question on leetcode and observed that O(NlogN) algorithm performs better than O(N).
https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-characters-by-frequency
Solution 1:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
        return ''.join(char * occurences for char, occurences in Counter(s).most_common())

Analyzed complexity by leetcode

Runtime

Solution 2:
    def frequencySort(self, s: str) -> str:
        count = Counter(s)
        buckets = defaultdict(list)

        for char, cnt in count. items(): 
            buckets[cnt].append(char)
        res = []

        for i in range(len(s), 0, -1): 
            for c in buckets[i]:
                res.append(c * i)

        return "".join(res)

Analyzed complexity by leetcode

Runtime


Leetcode runtime calculation is not accurate.

Asymptotic time complexity does not always reflect actual runtime, especially on smaller inputs.

both are O(N). Counter(s).most_common() has a sort, so thats where you might think the logN comes from, but the maximum size of Counter(s) is 52 (one  frequency per upper/lowercase character), so really the sort happens in O(1), and the rest is O(N).

For i = 1 to N: wait(1 second); EndFor is O(n) and it would take 5 seconds for n = 5. For i = 1 to N: For i = 1 to N: wait(1 milliseconds); EndFor  EndFor is O(n^2) and takes 25 milliseconds for n = 5. Complexity does not map directly to runtime. It's a useful way to know how an algorithm will handle larger inputs. But isn't supposed to measure runtime. Moreover, the nature of the big-O notation is to omit other constants. So wait(1 minute) For i = 1 to N: wait(1 millisecond); EndFor is O(n) and even though it only grows with 1ms per n, it's slower than the O(n^2) before.

@VLAZ The difference between O(n) and O(n^2) is usually pretty noticeable unless you have something extremely slow like this wait(1 minute) (or if the bottleneck of the algorithm is interacting with a human user); however the difference between O(n log(n)) and O(n) is pretty hard to see even for relatively big values of n, because log grows very slowly. For instance log2(1000000) is only 20.

@Stef the point I'm making is that complexity doesn't necessarily mean the runtime is better. It's entirely possible the runtime per n is different. I used extreme values just to illustrate the point but the difference may be more subtle and only really show up for large inputs. Yet for low one, even worse complexity algorithm can work better. Classical example is quicksort (which is fast, hence the name) vs bubble sort (one of the worst complexities for sorting) - for low number of elements, bubble sort wins in runtime.

@VLAZ And I was adding an argument to your point by pointing out that constant * n can easily be larger than log(n) * n

Big-O is not about the speed. It is about scalability of algorithm.
And I don't think O(N) solution is actually O(N), because you have nested loop. It is more O(N * M), where N - length of s and M - number of unique letters, because you iterate over string s and takes all letters from bucket with it's occurrences.
Now let's take a look at the code.

In first example we have only 2 loops - one in Counter under the hood and one comprehension style (and yes, one as join).
In second we have Counter creation, iterating over Counter and nested loops. Add to this appending element to the array (and yes, join, again).

List comprehension is a little bit faster in most cases, than appending elements to existing list, and you have less loops in the first example.
Hope this will help you to figure it out!
